# django logging, how not to repeat the error messages into different handler?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to redirect only ERROR/CRITICAL to file1, and DEBUG to file2

I am trying with below approach.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple' : {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fDebugHandler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': 'file1.log'
        },

        'fErrorHandler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': 'file2.log'
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        'vpe_default': {
            'handlers': ['fDebugHandler', 'fErrorHandler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The problem here is  all the debug information that comes in file1, also appears in file2. That's obvious because of the logger level.

Is there any way to get functionalities like only **DEBUG**,  or only **ERROR** & **DEBUG**

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/#filters) (more info from the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)).

From the docs, you can do something like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple' : {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'excludedebugmsgs': {
            '()': 'yourproject.logging.ExcludeDebug',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fDebugHandler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': 'file1.log'
        },

        'fErrorHandler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': 'file2.log',
            'filters': ['excludedebugmsgs']
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        'vpe_default': {
            'handlers': ['fDebugHandler', 'fErrorHandler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Then you would need to write `yourproject.logging.ExcludeDebug` according to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)

There are some [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/#id4) in the Django docs.